# spark sql failed to recognize hive partition columns

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a partitioned table `event_fact`. The partition columns are `dt, type`. And then I create a view on top of that table.

```
create view event_fact_view as select 
dt, type, columnA, columnB, collect_list(columnC) 
from event_fact 
group by dt, type, columnA, columnB;
```

And when I run the query below, spark-sql will do a full table scan on event_fact regardless of the partition columns. However, if I run the same sql on hive, it is able to recognize that.

```
select * from event_fact_view where dt='20190501' and type='A';
```

As I identified, the issue is to do with the UDF `collect_list`, if I remove the "collect_list", spark sql is able to filter first and then group by. Is this a known issue to spark sql? I could not find any documentation or JIRA related with this. Is there any other way to `collect_list`?